# На странице в справке про отключение рекламы нету абзаца про то, где управлять настройками показа рекламы

Tags: дефект, локализация, справка, привилегии, реклама

Наша: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads

Их: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads

У нас нет абзаца:

> ## But what if I still want to see those ads?
>
> If you decide that you really like seeing banner ads because they're useful or interesting to you, then you can disable this privilege in
>   your profile. Click on "Edit Profile & Settings", then click on
>   "Preferences". There will be an option for re-enabling these ads,
>   should you wish:
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> We want to emphasize that you should only re-enable banner ads if you
>   want to see them, not because you're trying to support us financially.
>   In fact, it doesn't really do us any good to show you ads for products
>   that you don't want to engage with. So make the decision that's best
>   for you, and that's the one that's best for us too.

Answer (score 2):

#### Но что если я всё равно хочу видеть объявления?

Если вы хотите видеть объявления и считаете, что они полезны и интересны вам,  то вы можете возобновить их показ в своём профиле. Для этого нажмите <kbd>Редактировать профиль</kbd> -> <kbd>Предпочтения</kbd> и настройте показ рекламы:

[image]

Мы подчёркиваем, что включать рекламу следует, если вы действительно хотите её видеть, а не потому, что вы хотите поддержать нас финансово.
Нам бесполезно показывать вам рекламу продуктов, которые вам неинтересны. Поэтому решайте так, как вы считаете нужным. Это будет лучше и для нас.

Comment: Перевёл абзац. Скриншот тоже заменил, так же поправил устаревшую информацию (например, про то, как найти флажок отключения рекламы). Если у вас есть идеи, как можно улучшить перевод, то смело редактируйте, ибо для этого нужно всего 100 баллов репутации.